# The difference in performance of different memory mount in dell poweredge R430

Tags: performance, memory, hardware, dell-poweredge

There are 3 servers R430 (S1, S2, S3). All of them have 2 procesors and 8*8GB of ram in slots A1-A4 and B1-B4.

There is a need of extending memory.

I've read dell recomendations (http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN296980#SampleConfig) and i see 2 possibilites:

1. buy 8*16GB ram, put it to S1, and memory from S1 put into S2 and S3.
2. buy 3*8GB ram, and add it to S1..S3.

In first case - there will be 128GB ram in S1, and 96GB ram in S2 and S3.
In second - there will be on every machine 96GB ram.

Does anybody knows what difference of speed can i expect in 1 and 2 scenario in comparsion to current situation?
I expect that situation where memory is not equally mounted between processors will reduce performance. But - how much drop of performance can i expect in both cases? 1%? 10%? Where will be smaller?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](http://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Comment: i don't think. I don't look for capacity planing - i'm looking for information how big is difference in performance between different configuration.

Comment: Unless someone has the exact same hardware as you and is willing to perform tests for you, you'll need to test it yourself.

Comment: not exactly the same hardware - i think less specific - how is performance difference when are used different different modules. Is that 1%? 5%? Or 30%? the same problem is on all servers which allow now equally puting memory to slots.